# Is "click event on node" works with Mermaid js in angular?

Tags: angular, mermaid

I am trying to integrate Mermaid flowchart drawing Javascript in my angular 9 based client application.  I am able to draw the flowchart diagram, but I do have requirement to provide click event on a particular node with function defined in Typescript (component file).
Can someone please provide how to solve this issue with example?

Here is the code that I have
html : <div #mermaid>
TS:

```
@ViewChild('mermaid', { static: true }) mermaid: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit () {
    mermaid.initialize(this.config);
    const element: any = this.mermaid.nativeElement;
    const graphDefinition = `graph TD\nA[Christmas] -->|Get money| B(Go shopping)\nB --> C(Let me think)\nC -->|One| D[Laptop]\nC -->|Two| E[iPhone]\nC -->|Three| F[fa:fa-car Car]\nA[Christmas] -->|Get money| D[Laptop]\nB --> E \nclick A CustomFunction`;

    let _local = this;
    var insertSvg = function(svgCode, bindFunctions){
      element.innerHTML = svgCode;
      bindFunctions(element);
};
var id = 'theGraph';
mermaid.render(id,graphDefinition,insertSvg, element);
}

CustomFunction = function() {
     alert("Hello World");
 };
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 3):

I solved this problem on angular 7 but with bad method. I will use until close this issue with correct code metod.

I added click event this code "click a1 call sessionStorage.setItem(ClickedNode,a1)" and i read sessionStorage on runtime with this code:

ngOnInit() {

```
setInterval(() => {

    let nodeId = sessionStorage.getItem("ClickedNode");

    if (nodeId) {

       if (nodeId == "a1") {

           // Todos

       }

    }

    sessionStorage.removeItem("ClickedNode");

});
```

}